# Active Directory server Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

We want check with `AD` if user exists then login otherwise redirect to another page.

I have all parameter like.

```
"CN=XXX103XXX,
 OU=Domain Controllers,DC=ad,DC=XXXXediaXXXX,
 DC=net"
Server Name: "XXXXXX.net" "
```

How to check user if exist in AD then login otherwise redirect to antoehr page?

I tried this example but it isn't working.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authenticate-a-user-against-the-active-directory/

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Where is your code?

Comment: have you considered using `PrincipalContext` along with other simple / basic AD functions available in C#.NET